# Multiple random choices with different outcomes

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make a random NPC generator in Python--the last time I tried this, it was in PHP, and that went. . . strangely. What I'd like to be able to do with this is to call the defined variables within the string multiple times. I can do that by running a `for i in range(n)` loop, but that gets me the same random choice every time.

I've been looking, and I'm not totally sure that I've found how to call that function multiple times and get different results each time.

```
import random
gend = [ 'male', 'female' ]
race = [ 'Human', 'Elf', 'Orc', 'Halfling', 'Gnome', 'Half-Elf', 'Half-Orc', 'Outsider' ]
pers = [ 'leader-like, optimistic', 'bad-tempered, irritable', 'relaxed, peaceful', 'quiet, analytical' ]
hook = [ 'a chore that needs doing', "some concerns for another's well-being", 'an item that needs retrieving/delivering',
    'a grudge', 'a person/organization in their way', 'a target on his or her back', 'an indiscretion that needs covering up',
    'a debt that needs paying' ]
randgend = random.choice(gend)
randrace = random.choice(race)
randpers = random.choice(pers)
randhook = random.choice(hook)
print("A {} {}, with a {} disposition and {}.".format(randgend, randrace, randpers, randhook))
```

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing? What are you expecting as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
randgend = random.choice(gend)
```

makes `randgend` a **single random choice** from `[ 'male', 'female' ]`, you're basically writing:

```
randgend = 'male'  # or female, whichever gets picked first
```

If you want it to be a function that returns *a different random choice each time*, you need:

```
randgend = lambda: random.choice(gend)
```

(see [the docs on `lambda` expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)) then call it:

```
print("A {} {}, with a {} disposition and {}.".format(
    randgend(),  # note parentheses
    ...,
))
```

---

Alternatively, much easier, just move the call to `random.choice`:

```
print("A {} {}, with a {} disposition and {}.".format(
    random.choice(gend),
    ...,
))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function.Try this

```
def myrandfunction():
    randgend = random.choice(gend)
    randrace = random.choice(race)
    randpers = random.choice(pers)
    randhook = random.choice(hook)
    return ("A {} {}, with a {} disposition and {}.".format(randgend, randrace, randpers, randhook))

>>>print(myrandfunction())
"A female Elf, with a relaxed, peaceful disposition and some concerns for another's well-being."
>>>print(myrandfunction())
'A male Half-Orc, with a leader-like, optimistic disposition and an indiscretion that needs covering up.'
```

If you not want to repeat sentence, use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html)

```
>>>from itertools import product
>>>myrandoms = product(gend,race,pers,hook)

>>>"A {} {}, with a {} disposition and {}.".format(*[i for i in next(myrandoms)])
'A male Human, with a bad-tempered, irritable disposition and an item that needs retrieving/delivering.'
>>>"A {} {}, with a {} disposition and {}.".format(*[i for i in next(myrandoms)])
'A male Human, with a leader-like, optimistic disposition and an indiscretion that needs covering up.'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this also

```
print("A {} {}, with a {} disposition and {}.".format(random.choice(gend), random.choice(race), random.choice(pers), random.choice(hook)))
```